# how to restric users not to enter special characters in text box using angularjs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, special-characters

Below is my code, for editable drop down.

```
<div class="form-group has-success" name="projectForm" style="margin-left:30%;"> 
     <label for="select2" class="control-label">Select Project</label>
     <div class="select-editable" id="select2">
         <select ng-options="item.label for item in projectValues track by item.id" ng-change="getDataOnProjectLoad(selectedProject)" ng-model="selectedProject">
         <input type="text" name="Project" value="select" ng-model="selectedProject.label"  id="txtProject"  required />
     </div>
</div>
```

And if user tries to enter special character inside this editable drop down an error message should be displayed !!!

Comment: What would be a special character for you? Or if that is to many, what characters are allowed?

Comment: all the special characters like ~@!#$%^&*()_+-= etc. only alphanumeric is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sort of regex matching in your controller should do the trick, I'd imagine:

```
$scope.labelIsAlphanumeric = function() {
  $scope.selectedProject.label.match(/^[0-9a-z]*$/i)
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<div ng-hide="labelIsAlphanumeric()" class="error-message">
  Selected project label has non-alphanumeric characters!
</div>
```